# Scala Akka and Protocol Buffers

Tags: scala, akka, protocol-buffers

I'm playing around with Akka's remoting and serialization facilities and want to understand a few things to get started. I've read over the documentation on serialization here:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/serialization.html

According to the documentation, it seems that it would be enough to just supply these things in my application.conf, under:

```
akka.actor {

 serializers {
   java = "akka.serialization.JavaSerializer"
   proto = "akka.remote.serialization.ProtobufSerializer"
}

 serialization-bindings {
    "com.mycompany.messages.MyMessage" = proto
 }
}
```

And let's assume I have a case class under that package, such as:

```
package com.mycompany.messages;
case class MyMessage(name: String, year: Int)
```

And then in my actors, I can simly do something like this:

```
class ClientActor extends Actor {

     def receive = {
        case x: MyMessage => ...
     }
}
```

Would this configuration be enough, or would I need to do something more?
I've looked at an external serializer mentioned from the documentation here:
https://github.com/romix/akka-protostuff-serialization

This looks really promising, but I was looking for something standard that comes out of the box from Akka.

I'm also looking into testing for message version compatibility. Let's say **Actor A** talks to **Actor B** with **MessageX**

**MessageX** initially might contain fields like this:

```
a: String, b: String, c: String
```

Now let's say Actor B upgrades its version of **Message X**, lets call it **Message X +1**

**Message X +1** now includes another field, like so:

```
a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String
```

But **Actor A** is still sending the older version of the message, just simply **Message X**... would **Actor B** still know how to deserialize the old message?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Protobuf serializer can only serialize Protobuf messages. So for things to work as you want you need to make MyMessage a protobuf message.

Comment: Could you provide more details: `how to make MyMessage a protobuf message`? Or any useful link?

Comment: This is quite old but I guess this should help someone who stumbles upon this - You define `MyMessage` in a `.proto` file and compile it with a protobuf compiler like ScalaPB. This generates (among other things) a case class which you can then use in your code. And since this class extends from `com.google.protobuf.Message` you can bind your akka protobuf serializer to it in the conf file, and that's it. Feel free to mention me in the comments if you need an elaborate answer. I'll be happy to.

Answer (score 3):

Just an additional information on your versioning concerns;

Protobuf can serialise/ deserialize different versions of the same message types. You have to sustain the already present fields' indexes and add the additional new ones accordingly, in your proto file descriptor.